# Problem involving time dilation

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

Let us suppose a spaceship has left earth with velocity $v$ and after crossing a certain distance $d$ from earth, a light signal is sent from earth(which assume travels in the speed of light). At some point the light signal will cross the spaceship.

Let us suppose the time taken to meet the spaceship is $t_0$ with respect to earth and $t$ with respect to the astronaut. Now is it reasonable to conclude that $t=\frac{t_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$? I am having problems understanding why this is true.

First of all this time dilation relation was established taking $t_0$ as proper time and $t$ as improper time. *The definition of proper time interval only works when the event is occuring in the same frame i.e the event is at rest with respect to the frame*. But going along with that here the earth is at rest but the light signal(which is our event) is not at rest relative to earth. So how us the above formula working in our case? If i learnt any concept wrong,please enlighten me with the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

In your scenario there are two events: A) person on Earth sends signal, B) person in spaceship receives signal.  You want to know the time interval between events A and B in both people's reference frames.

You are correct that the standard time dilation equation is only true when one of the of the observers is co-moving with the events.  That means both events happen at the same place for one of the observers.  For your events A and B, that is not the case.

The general thing to do is to assign coordinates to both events in one reference frame $(t_A, x_A)$ and $(t_B, x_B)$.  The time interval measured in this reference frame is $\Delta t = t_B - t_A$.  Then you can use the Lorentz transformations to determine the coordinates of the same events in the other frame.

$$c t_A^\prime = \gamma\left(c t_A - \frac{v}{c} x_A\right)$$
$$c t_B^\prime = \gamma\left(c t_B - \frac{v}{c} x_B\right)$$

The time interval measured in the other frame would be $\Delta t^\prime = t_B^\prime - t_A^\prime$.

Since you only care about time intervals and not the individual time coordinates, the [invariant interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Spacetime_interval), $\Delta s^2$, can be used to directly relate $\Delta t$ and $\Delta x$ to $\Delta t^\prime$ and $\Delta x^\prime$.

You might ask, whose proper time is the time interval between A and B?  The answer is no one's.  Events A and B both happen where the light signal is, so you might be tempted to say it is the signal's proper time.  However, there is no inertial frame where the light signal is at rest.

Proper time only exists for events that are **timelike** separated.  Events A and B are **lightlike** or **null** separated.

Comment: Thank you,a humble question,then do you mean the time dilation equation method is wrong as i stated?

Comment: It does not apply to this problem.  But it is true if one of the time intervals is one of the observer's proper time.

Answer (score 0):

The formula of time dilation applies directly if the ship compares $\Delta t_s$ with $\Delta t_e$. Where $\Delta t_s$ is the time of travel according to the clock of the ship. $\Delta t_e$ is the difference between the time in the destiny and the time when leaving the earth, supposing those clocks (earth and destiny) synchronized, what is possible because they are supposed in the same frame.

Supposing time is zero for ship and earth when the ship leaves earth, $$t_e = \frac{d}{v} + t_0$$
Now, we do the trick of supposing the signal reaches the ship exactly when it passes by a planet with clocks synchronized with the earth:
$$\gamma t_s = (\frac{d}{v} + t_0) \implies t_s = \frac{(\frac{d}{v} + t_0)}{\gamma}$$